# Enum scope is not accessible through structure in Class in C++

Tags: c++

There is one problem I am facing in access and initializing the enum and structure as described
There is one Header file defined as for `sample.h` have content as

```
class MyClass{

   enum M1 {
          MY_VAL1 = 0, 
          MY_VAL2,
          MY_VAL3
    };

   enum M2 {
          MY_VA1 = 0, 
          MY_VA2,
          MY_VA3
    };


   enum M3 {
          MY_V1 = 0, 
          MY_V2,
          MY_V3
    };

  struct val {
        M1 obj1;  
        M2 obj2;
        M3 obj3;
   };  

};
```

In the `sample.cpp` I am initializing or accessing as

```
#include "sample.h"

MyClass mObj = { {MY_VAL1}, {MY_VA1}, {MY_V1} };
```

But always complain about that "`MY_VAL1`", "`MY_VA1`", "`MY_V1`" not defined in the scope.

Comment: Those are in the scope of `MyClass`, write `MyClass::MY_VAL1` etc

Answer (score 3):

Your enum types are not public, and you are not qualifying the member type names.  It seems that you want some member variables, instead of declaring `struct MyClass::val`:

```
class MyClass{
public:
   enum M1 {
          MY_VAL1 = 0, 
          MY_VAL2,
          MY_VAL3
    };

   enum M2 {
          MY_VA1 = 0, 
          MY_VA2,
          MY_VA3
    };


   enum M3 {
          MY_V1 = 0, 
          MY_V2,
          MY_V3
    };

    M1 obj1;
    M2 obj2;
    M3 obj3;
};

static const MyClass foo = { MyClass::MY_VAL1, MyClass::MY_VA1, MyClass::MY_V1 };
```

Comment: I am surprised that works; I would expect name collisions with the three different `MyClass::MY_VAL1`s.

Comment: Perhaps you didn't read closely - `MY_VAL1`, `MY_VA1`, `MY_V1`.  That's one thing the question *did* get right!

Comment: Oh, yeah, that explains it. I always just use `enum class` when I can get away with it, and then I don’t need to do that kind of thing.

Answer (score 2):

All of these enums are not defined in the scope of main, instead they are defined inside your class. Use scope resolution operator (i.e. `::`) to solve this. Note that using `::` is still problematic in your case, since the `enums` are private. Change them to `public` for the `::` to work.

```
... 
main(){
...
        int x = MyClass::MY_VA1;
...
    }
```

*I'm not using your example, as it gives other errors...*

Comment: The enums are private inside MyClass. Unless the access  is specified as public inside MyClass, the code in main will not work - compile error MY_VA1 is private.

Comment: True. I compiled it on my machine with this change too, but forgot to mention it. Thx!